# WSO2 ESB Callout Mediator axis2Configuration

Tags: wso2, esb, mediator, callout

I have a question regarding the WSO2 ESB callout mediator using an individual Axis2 configuration file. I would like to have the individual Axis2 configuration to be deployed using a carbon application. Unfortunately the callout mediator doesn't seem to be able to read the Axis2 configuration from the registry. I'm getting an error that the file axis2_blocking_client_proxy.xml can't be resolved when I deploy the carbon application that contains the mediation with my callout mediator.

The deployment works when I Quote a relative file path that points to the configuration file. Does anybody know if there is a way to tweak carbon application files so that distinct resources will be written to a dedicated directory on the WSO2 ESB Server?

Best regards,

Heiko

Answer (score 0):

AFAIU, your requirement is to deploy an axis2 configuration file using a CAR (carbon application) file. This is not a recommended approach. If you need to deploy a configuration file in to the ESB, you can deploy that during the server creation time. CAR files are used to deploy the actual implementation code rather than the static configuration files.